# How to avoid orphan processes multiprocessing and subprocess in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, subprocess

My function `entry_function()` first uses `ProcessPool` (from `pebble`) to work several tasks concurrently. Each of the tasks includes invoking an external jar file by `subprocess.run()`.

Unfortunately, the external jar is unstable; sometimes it crashes. If any of the external jars crashes, I want to stop everything and exit `entry_function()` with a proper exit code. This is because each execution of an external jar takes much time, and I want to save time as much as possible.

The problem is, when I call `future.cancel()` for the processes invoked by ProcessPool, it does not terminate their child processes (i.e., external jars). As a result, the processes for the external jars become orphan processes.

This is the summary of my code:

```py
import subprocess
from pebble import ProcessPool

def entry_function():
    with ProcessPool() as pool:
    future = pool.map(worker, iterables)

    try:
        for res in future.result():
        collected_res += res

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("CalledProcessError: %s" % e.cmd)
        future.cancel()  # this terminates (and cancels) worker processes
        return None

    return collected_res

def worker(item):
    # prepare cmd
    p = subprocess.run(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=3600)  # this process is not killed and becomes an orphan process
    p.check_returncode()

    # do something with p.stdout
    return res
```

How can I avoid making orphan processes for the external jars in this case?

Comment: What OS are you using? Please format the code in a usable format or people won't be able to reproduce your code. Lastly, calling `future.cancel()` after `future.result()` has no effect as the task is already complete at that point. You need to call `future.cancel()` only to stop tasks which are in progress.